# Nginx: logging full request data?

Tags: nginx

Simply, is it possible to make `nginx` log all the request information (source address, protocol, headers, etc.)? Especially, in some parseable format.

Comment: nginx can log anything that's in any of its variables. Have you read the documentation yet?

Comment: @MichaelHampton that means I'd have to list all the variables specifically. Which is what I am doing, but the question is: is it possible to log any custom header without listing it explicitly?

Comment: You should edit your question to make it more clear. Many people do not see the comments, and having to read them all to figure out the question makes it difficult to help.

Comment: Generally for that level of detail you would capture the raw traffic and use tools like Wireshark to analyze it.

Answer (score 1):

The log format can contain common variables, and variables that exist only at the time of a log write:

**$bytes_sent**    the number of bytes sent to a client
**$connection**    connection serial number
**$connection_requests**    the current number of requests made through a connection
**$msec**    time in seconds with a milliseconds resolution at the time of the log write
**$pipe**    “p” if request was pipelined, “.” otherwise
**$request_length**    request length (including request line, header, and request body)
**$request_time**    request processing time in seconds with a milliseconds resolution; 
**$status**    response status
**$time_iso8601**    local time in the ISO 8601 standard format
**$time_local**    local time in the Common Log Format

[RTFM!!!](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html)

Comment: Sorry for the bad question wording. I was asking if it is possible to do something like 'log_format ... $(json_dump $request)' so that whichever request data was passed is saved in the log (including all the headers and data and so on that I wouldn't be able to list explicitly). It does seem that that should be possible with the lua module, though.